# Scrolling in PuTTY not working

Tags: windows-xp, ssh, putty, scrolling

As you all can see in the image below, the vertical scroll in PuTTY on my old WIN-XP computer is not working.
The vertical scroll-bar is disabled.
This becomes a problem when I enter a command that prints a whole bunch of words, such as HELP in this case or DIR for example.

[Scrollback on Putty](https://superuser.com/questions/449077/scrollback-on-putty)
https://superuser.com/questions/729411/using-scroll-options-in-putty-terminal

These similar questions provided no answers/tips apart from

> Is the option "Display scrollbar" enabled?

But I am sure I have it enabled in the settings under the "Window" tab
Is there any other way to enable vertical scrolling or am I doing something wrong?
Using release 0.63...

EDIT
I have the exact same problem on my WIN-8

[image]
[image]

EDIT
This problem holds not only for SSH but also Telnet
Are there other users experiencing this problem?
Using FreeSSH for my server, which turned out to be the problem

Comment: Are you SSH-ing into a Windows computer, or what type of connection are you using?

Comment: @Brian Yes I am using SSH

Comment: What version of putty are you using?  Does this only happen on windows sessions or does it affect *nix as well?  My gut tells me that you're probably running into an issue/limitation of what you're connecting to rather than a problem with your putty install.

Comment: <nod>, those scrollback settings match mine. Agree @Foosh. Strange that PuTTY wouldn't override scroll settings, though -- it should just be client-side data retention, right?

Comment: That is the latest release verion http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html

Comment: PuTTY negotiates that with the remote machine somewhat.  Ever try to use PuTTY with an AIX or HP-UX machine?  It doesn't play nicely with resize so you have to run the commands manually.  Same goes for launching screen.

Comment: Yecch @Foosh. No, I've only ever SSH-ed into Debian and Gentoo machines. Mramaa, per Foosh, yes, it probably does matter. If you have a Linux machine you could try connecting to as a sanity check, I'd give that a shot.

Comment: That was the missing piece of the puzzle.  Here's your question and a possible [answer](http://superuser.com/questions/255013/cant-see-more-than-the-first-few-lines-in-an-ssh-connection)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the limitations of connecting to Windows machines is that Windows doesn't have the same sense of "terminal" that a *nix machine does (history lessons aside, Windows was built for personal use, *nix was built for shared use).  Utilities like FreeSSH try to mimic the terminal capabilities of *nix on Windows but does so imperfectly since it has to do all the rendering server-side.  This means of course that the only things PuTTY "sees" is the control characters used to render the contents of the screen rather than the actual characters.

You might be able to work around this by using Cygwin and OpenSSH on the remote machine to get a little closer to *nix-like operation.  I have not tried this myself so I do not know how well it would work.

Another option is to use [PowerShell Server](http://www.powershellserver.com/download/) on the remote server.  It seems like it's more fully featured than freessh and is probably the best solution plus it's free for personal use.

Reference questions:

[Can't see more than the first few lines in an ssh connection](https://superuser.com/questions/255013/cant-see-more-than-the-first-few-lines-in-an-ssh-connection)

[A decent remote shell from UNIX to Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/582725/a-decent-remote-shell-from-unix-to-windows)